# Invocar os valores selecionados nas CheckBox na View Editar

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Não sei como retornar os valores selecionados nas *checkBox* para a *View*.

Controlador:

```
public ActionResult Editar(int? id)
{
    // acedendo a um conjunto de valores de uma classe
    ViewBag.Daylist = GetDias(null);
    return View(inscricao);
}
```

Método Auxiliar:

```
private MultiSelectList GetDias(string[] selectedValues)
{
    List<DiasSemana> Dias = new List<DiasSemana>()
    {
        new DiasSemana() { ID = 0, Dia= "Domingo" },
        new DiasSemana() { ID = 1, Dia= "Segunda-Feira" },
        new DiasSemana() { ID = 2, Dia= "Terça-Feira" },
        new DiasSemana() { ID = 3, Dia= "Quarta-Feira" },
        new DiasSemana() { ID = 4, Dia= "Quinta-Feira" },
        new DiasSemana() { ID = 5, Dia= "Sexta-Feira" },
        new DiasSemana() { ID = 6, Dia= "Sábado" },
    };
    return new MultiSelectList(Dias, "ID", "Dia", selectedValues);
}
```

View:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Dias_Preferencial, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })

    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input type="checkbox" id="allcheck" />
        @Html.Label("Todos", new { @class = "control-label" })  <br />
        @foreach (var item in (MultiSelectList)ViewBag.Daylist)
        {                                
            <input type="checkbox" name="SelectDias" value="@item.Text" class="checkbox-inline" />
            @Html.Label(item.Text, new { @class = "control-label" })
            <br />
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Você ta colocando um name igual para todos os checkbox, então no seu model deve receber "SelectDias"

Comment: Não percebi, podia me mostrar?

Comment: Desculpe..se entendi bem agora,relendo, vc precisa de popular seu drop com os valores do metodo auxiliar certo? se for isso crie um enum e passe ele diretamento pro DROPDOWNLIST desta forma....

`@Html.DropDownList("MyType", 
   Html.GetEnumSelectList(typeof(MyType)) , 
   "Select My Type", 
   new { @class = "form-control" })`

Comment: Qualquer duvida, segue o [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388483/how-do-you-create-a-dropdownlist-from-an-enum-in-asp-net-mvc]

Comment: Isto não é nenhuma DropdownList, mas sim uma lista de Checkbox.

Comment: Desculpe... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11904410/populate-and-retrieve-data-in-checkbox-list-on-mvc3

Answer (score 0):

Esta é a maneira ruim de fazer. A maneira correta envolve usar [`@Html.ListBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.listbox(v=vs.118).aspx) ou ainda [`@Html.ListBoxFor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.listboxfor(v=vs.118).aspx):

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectDias, (MultiSelectList)ViewBag.Daylist)
```